# PHP Doctrine 2 - How to save One To Many relationship automatically with Cascade options

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, cascade

I'm not being able to save a relationship in Doctrine 2 with Cascade.
In my application, Computers have many Actions, as well as an Action can belong to many different Computers. But I also have an extra attribute, Active, to specify which Actions will be Active **per Computer**.

My Tables are the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS computers (
      id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      os VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
      date_creation TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      date_modification TIMESTAMP,
      online BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
      id_user_creation INT,
      id_user_modification INT DEFAULT NULL,

      CONSTRAINT fk_users_computers_creation FOREIGN KEY (id_user_creation) REFERENCES users(id),
      CONSTRAINT fk_users_computers_modification FOREIGN KEY (id_user_modification) REFERENCES users(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS actions (
      id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      description TEXT,
      date_creation TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      date_modification TIMESTAMP,
      id_user_creation INT NOT NULL,
      id_user_modification INT DEFAULT NULL,

      CONSTRAINT fk_users_actions_creation FOREIGN KEY (id_user_creation) REFERENCES users(id),
      CONSTRAINT fk_users_actions_modification FOREIGN KEY (id_user_modification) REFERENCES users(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS computers_actions (
      id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      id_computer INT NOT NULL,
      id_action INT NOT NULL,
      active BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,

      CONSTRAINT fk_computers FOREIGN KEY (id_computer) REFERENCES computers(id),
      CONSTRAINT fk_actions FOREIGN KEY (id_action) REFERENCES actions(id)
);
```

The code above is only a slice of my database script, the one who is affected by my current problem.
My entities are the following:

The Computer Entity:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ComputerAction", mappedBy="computer", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $actions;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->actions = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

The Action Entity:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ComputerAction", mappedBy="action", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $computers;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->computers = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

The relationship, ComputerAction Entity.
I need an attribute on this relationship, that's why I didn't use the ManyToMany annotation.
In this case, a Computer has many ComputerAction, and a ComputerAction has only one Computer. The same happens to the Action.

```
/**
 * @var Computer
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Computer", inversedBy="actions", cascade={"persist"})
 * @JoinColumn(name="id_computer", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $computer;

/**
 * @var Action
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Action", inversedBy="computers", cascade={"persist"})
 * @JoinColumn(name="id_action", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $action;

/**
 * @var boolean
 * @Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $active;
```

Those attributes have their own getters and setters, and as you can notice, the OneToMany ones have the Doctrine ArrayCollection type.

Adding Actions the my Computers is done in the action Add from the ComputerController, which follows below:

```
// ComputerController, action add

$computer->setName($post['name']);
$computer->setOs($post['os']);
$computer->setOnline(false);
$computer->setUserOwner($this->getUserService()->find($this->retrieveUser()['id']));

foreach($post['action'] as $id_action) {
    $relation = new ComputerAction();
    $relation->setAction($this->getActionService()->find($id_action));
    $relation->setComputer($computer);
    $computer->setActions($relation);
}

if($computer = $this->getComputerService()->save($computer)) {
    $this->setMessage(sprintf('Computer [%s] added successfully!', $computer->getName()), MessageSkin::SUCCESS);
} else {
    $this->setMessage('The Computer could not be added. Try again later.', MessageSkin::DANGER);
}
```

In the Computer Add view, I have a Select Multiple with Actions IDs. I get those IDs, and within a loop, I create a new ComputerAction, setting the $action attribute as the Action Entity that contains that ID. Then I set the current Computer in the $computer attribute, and finnaly, I add this instance of ComputerAction to the $actions ArrayCollection, within Computer Entity.

The problem is: why aren't the ComputerAction entities being saved?

I tried many different approaches with the Cascade options, but unsuccessful. Please help!

Thanks!

Siipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by setting the $active attribute to "false", as it cannot be null on the database. I don't know really why it happened since it's DEFAULT FALSE on the database. Doctrine just didn't warn me nor reported any error.

Answer (score 0):

You should remember that in any relationship Doctrine has main entity and mapped entity (slave entity) in an relationship. It is about OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToMany relationships and others. You can't save main entity from slave entity whatever you write.

This could help you perhaps.

Comment: I think I get your point. What am I supposed to do then? Save the relationship one by one, and then save the computer? Thanks!